# Llamar varaible php con un botón en html

Tags: php

He estado un rato probando cosas pero no encuentro lo que puede estar pasando.

Estoy intentando que al pulsar un botón te rediriga a otro archivo php, pero que la url del boton esté referenciada con un archivo php donde tengo todas las URLs para cuando mueva el proyecto de local al servidor.

Este el el código que tengo

**panel.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'WebServices/URLS.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])) : ?>
            <p>Estas logueado!</p>
            <p>ID: <?php echo $_SESSION['userId'];?></p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick='location.href = "<?php $url_logout ?>"'>Logout</button>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Y este es el documento en el que tengo la URL a la que quiero redirigir.

**URLS.php**

```
<?php
$url_logout = 'http://localhost/quien_es_quien/WebServices/logout.php';
?>
```

He puesto solo las partes importantes para que sea mas facil de ver. Me gustaría hacerlo sin AJAX por comodidad, pero ahora mismo no se me ocurre como puedo hacerlo. Estoy trabajando en XAMPP desde local.

Un saludo :)

Comment: ¿Y por qué no utilizas directamente un `FORM` que es HTML y evitas usar JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que puedas hacer uso de una variable que está en otro archivo lo puedes hacer por medio de `include()` como lo tienes en tu primer archivo.

No es necesario que utilices un `boton:submit` para poder ir a la **url**, basta con que hagas un enlace y le agregues la **url**.

```
<a href="<?= $url_logout ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Logout<a/>
```

Para utilizar tu código te hace falta él **echo** al momento de imprimir la variable **$url_logout** en el **PHP**.

Comment: Gracias! Me ha funcionado! Una pregunta, ¿Por qué has definido el href como `<?= $url_logout ?>` y no funciona si uso `<php? $url_logout ?>`?

Comment: El usar `<?= $variable ?>` es como usar `<?php echo $variable ?>`, pero cuando haces solamente `<?php $variable ?>` no haces nada, porque no la estás imprimiendo.